# Migration from Struts2 to Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, struts2, migration

I'm wishing to change my project over from Struts2 to Spring MVC.

My motivation for doing so is twofold:
1 - I wish to have my presentation framework able to correctly implement HTML5 tags
2 - Having been made redundant recently from a company that used Struts2 and no Spring, I now find that I'm lacking the skills to find new work

I first started this project using a maven archetype (I can't recall which one) and the pom was already configured with the following:

```
<properties>
    <struts.version>2.3.1</struts.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>${struts.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${struts.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${struts.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-sitemesh-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${struts.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${struts.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Yes, the project is using Spring but just the core for bean instantiation and dependency injection.

What I'd like to know is:
What do I need to replace these dependencies with to:
Maintain the version of sitemesh and spring core that were packaged with Struts 2.3.1?  (I've searched for 'Struts 2.3.1 bundled packages' and get this but no version next to the 'spring plugin' https://struts.apache.org/docs/guides.html)
Replace the core and remaining plugins with Spring MVC
Do I need an extra dependency for JSON support with spring as is the case with Struts?

I realise that once these have been swapped out, there'll be a huge task ahead refactoring to Spring.

Comment: Why don't you just look to see which Spring version is being pulled in? You could look at the effective pom, show the dependency tree, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Dave Newton for pointing me in the right direction.

Found the answer using

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Which shows that the struts2 spring plugin consists of:

```
+- org.apache.struts:struts2-spring-plugin:jar:2.3.1:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
|  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
|  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
|  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:compile
|  \- org.apache.struts:struts2-core:jar:2.3.1:compile
|     +- org.apache.struts.xwork:xwork-core:jar:2.3.1:compile
|     |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.3:compile
|     |  \- asm:asm-commons:jar:3.3:compile
|     |     \- asm:asm-tree:jar:3.3:compile
|     +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.18:compile
|     \- ognl:ognl:jar:3.0.3:compile
|        \- javassist:javassist:jar:3.11.0.GA:compile
```

So the answer: struts 2.3.1 has spring core etc. version 3.0.5